# Common Lisp: defstruct constructors and (declare (type blahblah blah))?

Tags: constructor, common-lisp, declare

Let's say I have this:

```
(defstruct (derp
            (:constructor
             make-derp
             (&key (dimension 4))))
  (some-bits (make-array (list dimension dimension)
                         :element-type 'bit
                         :initial-element 0)))
```

I'd like to be able to (declare (type ...) blahblahblah) the 'dimension' parameter.  Right now it accepts any value at all.  Sure, make-array will error out on 0-or-less, but I also want to declare the type to be within a range, or whatever else I wish to use declare type for.

So anyway, I tried adding (declare (type (integer 1 32) dimension)) to various places in this defstruct, but it always yields a different error.

No luck on a casual Google search of these terms.

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: declaring the type won't (necessarily) make the constructor *not* accept values other than the specified type.  Type declarations can be discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to declare it? Why not just check the type?

```
(defstruct (derp
            (:constructor
             make-derp (&key (dimension 4))))
  (some-bits (progn
               (check-type dimension (integer 0 10))
               (make-array (list dimension dimension)
                         :element-type 'bit
                         :initial-element 0))))
```

Generally above might not be robust enough. I'd then propose to write a `MAKE-SOMETHING` function, which does the checking upfront.

Note that you also can declare the type of the slot itself. Some CL will check that under some circumstances.

Comment: Upvoted, but it'd be nice to explicitly point out that a type declaration does not require the implementation to do any type checking.  As the answer shows, `check-type` is the right way to do this.

Comment: The reason is because I'm very into using Lisp's meta-documentation system as much as possible, and SBCL certainly puts type declarations both to enforcement use (when optimize safety is anything other than 0) and documentation when describing a function/method.  But I suppose this solution will work too, since it turns out DESCRIBE prints the (check-type ...) expression in the INITFORM, which is good, and more importantly it will show up to any third-party user who's doing scripting and needs to know exactly what legal values can be passed (even failing that, I can always just use docstrings)